# How to remove a row in a contingency table in R?

Tags: r

Let say I have a contingency table (made using the `table` function in R).

```
             digit
ID         1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
  1672120 23 16  8 10 12 13  3  3  5
  1672121  2  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0
  1672122  1  2  1  0  1  0  0  1  0
  1672123  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
  1672124  1  1  0  1  1  0  0  0  0
  1672125  5  2  5  1  1  1  0  0  2
  1672127  2  1  2  1  0  0  0  0  0
  1672128  2  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  1
  1672129  1  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0
```

If I want to remove the rows where the number of counts is smaller than 5 from the contingency table, how should I do it?

Comment: Please provide reproducible sample data using e.g. `dput` and expected output. Do you want to filter out rows where *any* count number is <5, or where *all* count numbers are <5, or where the sum of all count numbers is <5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't provide reproducible sample data here is an example based on the `mtcars` dataset

Let's create a count table of `mtcars$gear` vs. `mtcars$carb`

```
tbl <- table(mtcars$gear, mtcars$carb)
#
#    1 2 3 4 6 8
#  3 3 4 3 5 0 0
#  4 4 4 0 4 0 0
#  5 0 2 0 1 1 1
```

We then select only those rows where at least one count is larger than 2

```
tbl[apply(tbl > 2, 1, any), ]
#
#    1 2 3 4 6 8
#  3 3 4 3 5 0 0
#  4 4 4 0 4 0 0
```